# ui-router on Page Reload/Refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have my home page in the root directory, Home.html.
I then have my App folder setup like this.

App - > Equipment->Equipment.html

My ui-router setup is this.

```
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false});
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Home");
    $stateProvider
    .state('Home',{
        url:"/Home",
        templateUrl:'./App/Home/HomePart.html'

    .state('Equipment',{
        url:"/EquipmentBuilder",
        templateUrl:'./App/Equipment/Equipment.html',
        controller: 'EquipCtrl'
    });
```

Everything seems to work fine, until i go to the equipment page, and refresh manually... It then tries to go to Localhost/Equipment.html. Rather than keep the route, which would really be .App/Equipment/Equipment.html.

All im doing on the homepage is showing the view

```
 <div ui-view></div>
```

Why is it that it doesn't refresh the state, but rather tries to go to a page that does not exist.

Cant seem to find a solution to the refresh issue. People can't bookmark the page either, because it tries to bookmark LocalHost/Equipment, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Just a quick question: why did you set `requireBase` to `false`?

Comment: maybe you have some config problem with your `.htaccess` or `web.config` files (depend on the http server you're using)

Comment: U need an URL rewrite.

Comment: Are you not missing `})` after the first templateUrl ?